# Calling functions from other classes

Tags: c++, class, associations

I want to use a function from my `Page` class but I do not want to inherit from it. Is there another way I can use the`onPage(vector<string> vec)` function in my `element` and `elementX` class *without using inheritance?* Would association Work? I was thinking that.

Code is below:

```
class Page
{
    string str;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    void onPage(vector<string>vec);
};

class element
{
    Page p;
};

class elementX : public element
{
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it `public`, so foreign classes can access it.

```
class Page
{

   string str;
   vector<string>::iterator it;

 public:
   void onPage(vector<string>vec);


};
```

(you can use `public`, `private` and `protected` to control access to class members, make sure to read them all up. `private` is the default for classes).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The issue I can see is that you did not declare the `void onPage(vector<string>vec);` function as public (place `public:` before the function), since class members are `private` (hidden for other classes) in C++ by default.

Comment: ok yeas thanks i missed that so with pulic there i will be able to use the onPage(vector<string>vec) function in the element class?

Comment: Exactly. Another option is to declare the `element` class a `friend` of Page (`friend class element` inside `Page`) but that would be an extremely bad style.